# How to get the top 3 values mysql? Northwind Database

Tags: mysql, sql, northwind

I am doing some SQL practice in Toad for mySQL using the sample database Northwind.

The goal of this query is to get the top 3 customers in each month. Top meaning they spent the most money. I was able to join the tables and result with all of the Expenditure of each customer, but I can't get the top for each month.

This is my Query so far:

```css
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM orders.OrderDate) AS `Month`,
orders.CustomerID,`order details`.OrderID, 
ROUND(SUM((`order details`.UnitPrice * `order details`.Quantity)*(1 - `order details`.Discount)),2) AS Cost
FROM `order details`
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.OrderID = `order details`.OrderID
RIGHT JOIN customers ON customers.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY orders.OrderID, orders.CustomerID, `Month`
ORDER BY Month DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

I feel like I might need a loop of some kind to increment each month, but I don't know the format for that, but what would be a working solution?

Comment: Your tags / question title are quite misleading. Northwind is a sample database for Microsoft SQL server, but you're asking about MySQL, which is something quite different. Could you please edit your question and fix this information?

Comment: I downloaded the MySQL version of Northwind, so I believe what I said remains accurate

Comment: Now I'm curious - where did you download it from? AFAIK, Microsoft doesn't offer a MySQL version of the Northwind DB.

Comment: Took me an hour of searching yesterday. I found it [here](https://code.google.com/p/northwindextended/downloads/detail?name=Northwind.MySQL5.sql). Its available other different SQL servers as well.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`for month in  6 5 4 ; do mysql -u root database_name -BNe
"SELECT '"$month"' AS Month,orders.CustomerID,
order_details.OrderID,
ROUND(SUM((order_details.UnitPrice * order_details.Quantity)*(1 - order_details.Discount)),2) AS Cost 
FROM order_details LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.OrderID = order_details.OrderID 
RIGHT JOIN customers ON customers.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM orders.OrderDate)=$month
GROUP BY Month,orders.OrderID, orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY  Month DESC ,Cost Desc limit 3"; 
done`

Comment: That would give me the top 3 overall, but it won't give me the top 3 in each month.

Comment: in the for loop you can pass all the months for which you want to extract data.

Comment: Doesn't work because im not using a shell. Im using toad editor